# $T, S : V \to V$ linear transformations such that $S◦T = T◦S$. Prove that every eigenspace of $T$ is $S$-invariant.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> $T, S : V \to V$ linear transformations such that $S◦T = T◦S$. Prove that every eigenspace of $T$ is $S$-invariant.

I have seen this claim here - [$\mbox{Ker} \;S$ is T-invariant, when $TS=ST$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349127/mboxker-s-is-t-invariant-when-ts-st) but can't quite understand how to prove it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose **v** is an eigenvector of T. Then there is some scalar $\lambda$ such that T**v** = $\lambda$**v**. Scalars commute with everything, so ST**v** = S$\lambda$**v** = $\lambda$S**v**.

Since ST = TS, ST**v** = TS**v**, so $\lambda$S**v** = TS**v**

That can be rewritten as  T(S**v**) =  $\lambda$(S**v**)

In other words, S**v** is an eigenvector of T, with the same eigenvalue as **v**.